# Rotate an array of values around right bottom corner in python

Tags: python, numpy

I need to rotate the array of values to 90 degree around right bottom corner, that is all values on Ox for example would turn to oY.
[image]
I know it might be easy to do, but I couldn't manage make it so far neither with `np.rot90()` nor with other transformations

Comment: Please provide us with your code, so that we have context for how to help you.

Comment: Did you try np.reshape() or np.transpose() ? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.transpose.html

Comment: Have you tried `np.flip` ?

Comment: @florian transposition is not the same as rotation.

Comment: What is the problem you faced with `np.rot90`?

Comment: In which direction do you want to rotate? Clockwise or counter-clockwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it does not matter whether you rotate the array around the right bottom corner, the upper left corner or any other point: all of those are **just rotations**. The only aspect that matters a bit more is the direction in which you want the array to be rotated, clockwise or counter-clockwise, and, actually, you can get one using the other: rotate 90 degrees clockwise is the same as rotate 270 degrees in the opposite direction.

If you want to **rotate the array 90 degrees clockwise** use `np.rot90`, but tell `numpy` to rotate the array 3 times and, if you want to **rotate the array 90 degrees counter-clockwise** use `np.rot90` passing in `1` or nothing (besides the array, of course):

```
np.rot90(array)    # 90 deg CCW
np.rot90(array, 1) # 90 deg CCW
np.rot90(array, 3) # 90 deg CW
```

#### Example

```
import numpy as np

array = np.arange(15).reshape((3, 5))

print(array)

print(np.rot90(array, 1))
print(np.rot90(array, 3))
```

#### Original array

```
array([
    [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
    [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
    [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
])
```

#### Rotated 1 time (90 degrees counter-clockwise)

```
array([
    [ 4,  9, 14],
    [ 3,  8, 13],
    [ 2,  7, 12],
    [ 1,  6, 11],
    [ 0,  5, 10]
])
```

#### Rotated 3 times (90 degrees clockwise)

```
array([
    [10,  5,  0],
    [11,  6,  1],
    [12,  7,  2],
    [13,  8,  3],
    [14,  9,  4]
])
```

Answer (score -1):

Use np.swapaxes():

```
>>> x = np.array([[1,2,3]])
>>> np.swapaxes(x,0,1)
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Comment: This is not a rotation.